# Why won't my template class compile?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

http://pastebin.com/k7Czfi4S

I'm getting 18 errors.  The main one is it's saying the template has too many parameters.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Sorry.  Here's the errors:

```
Error   1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'maxSize' c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   30  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'maxSize' c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   36  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   7   error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'maxSize' c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   55  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   10  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'maxSize' c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   60  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   13  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'maxSize' c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   89  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   16  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'maxSize' c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   113 1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   6   error C2244: 'Queue<T,maxSize>::~Queue' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration    c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   52  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   15  error C2244: 'Queue<T,maxSize>::deque' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   110 1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   12  error C2244: 'Queue<T,maxSize>::enque' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   86  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   18  error C2244: 'Queue<T,maxSize>::examine' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration   c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   122 1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   9   error C2244: 'Queue<T,maxSize>::getCount' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration  c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   57  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   3   error C2244: 'Queue<T,maxSize>::Queue' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   32  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   2   error C2977: 'Queue' : too many template arguments  c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   30  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   5   error C2977: 'Queue' : too many template arguments  c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   36  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   8   error C2977: 'Queue' : too many template arguments  c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   55  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   11  error C2977: 'Queue' : too many template arguments  c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   60  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   14  error C2977: 'Queue' : too many template arguments  c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   89  1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate

Error   17  error C2977: 'Queue' : too many template arguments  c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\ooptest2016-queuetemplate\queue.hpp   113 1   OOPTest2016-QueueTemplate
```

Edit 2: Okay. it has been fixed.  With the help of n.m., I was able to get something that compiles.  I'll do my best to explain in case someone else comes along and sees this and is in a similar situation.

Since Node was an inner class of Queue, I had to use the scope resolution operator (`::`) to access it from the template.  I used `Queue<typename T, int maxSize>::Node` but the `typenames`'s were causing an issue.  What it should have said was `Queue<T, int>::Node`. I also did a couple other things wrong but they were all menial syntax errors.

Comment: Please post the code here, not a link to the code.

Comment: Can you post the errors please? You'll probably get more help that way

Comment: Replace all `Queue<typename T, int maxSize>` with `Queue<T, maxSize>`.

Comment: I added the error list.

Comment: @n.m. wow I didn't even catch that. Thanks. It fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, for example

```
template<typename T, int maxSize>
Queue<typename T, int maxSize>::Queue()                                                                                                                      
{
}
```

The first line,

```
template<typename T, int maxSize>
```

says that the following is parameterized by a `typename T` and an `int maxSize`. Following that, though, your class is `Queue<T, maxSize>`, so it should be

```
template<typename T, int maxSize>
Queue<T, maxSize>::Queue()                                                                                                                      
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to figure it out from a comment on the main post but this spells it out much better.